# ionic 5 ios dark theme shows shadow in the header on menu bar open and close

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I am trying to figure when the menubar is closed in ionic ios it shows some shadow styling in the header.

I looked into inspect element but couldn't figure exactly on what element that is being applied.

It seems it is around the `.toolbar-container` element! but not able to figure where exactly or how to fix that!

Here is a screenshot of captured transition and you can see the shadow:

[image]

Here is how it looks when after the side menu close:
[image]

btw this is the default dark theme for ios that comes with the ionic angular side menu.

Comment: What styling are you exactly talking about?

Comment: when the side menu is closing, you may see the shadow

Comment: That shadow is coming from `app.component.html` check css and remove it from there.

Comment: looks like it is somewhere in the header, still looking

Comment: Thanks @NajamUsSaqib for looking into it, finally found it it was `.header-background`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found it:

It was the `.header-background` when the menu is open (`.header-collapse-condense-inactive`) which was setting the backdrop for the header to be blur!

[image]

I just overwrite that with `backdrop-filter: none !important;` added the following CSS globally, fixed my problem!

```css
.header-collapse-condense-inactive .header-background {
  backdrop-filter: none !important;
}
```